# Iteration on a matrix

Tags: matrix, education, iteration

I want to update "matrix1" 100 times. "matrix3" will be new "matrix1" and it will iterate 100 times. Should I use a loop or function? First iteration is:

```
matrix1 = ( {
    {1, 2, 3},
    {4, 5, 6},
    {7, 8, 9}
   } );
matrix2 = matrix1*2 - 1;
matrix3 = matrix2 + 5;
matrix3
```

Output (First iteration):

```
{{6, 8, 10}, {12, 14, 16}, {18, 20, 22}}
```

matrix3 will be new matrix1

```
matrix1 = ( {
    {6, 8, 10},
    {12, 14, 16},
    {18, 20, 22}
   } );
matrix2 = matrix1*2 - 1;
matrix3 = matrix2 + 5;
matrix3
```

Output (Second iteration):

```
{{16, 20, 24}, {28, 32, 36}, {40, 44, 48}}
```

And, It will repeat 100 times.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
NestList[x \[Function] 2 x + 4, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}, 100]
```

Answer (score 7):

Another possibility is to write the problem via a recursion:

```
f[n_] := 2 f[n - 1] + 4;
f[1] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
```

To get any power, you then ask for

```
f[3]
{{16, 20, 24}, {28, 32, 36}, {40, 44, 48}}
```

or
    f[100]

Answer (score 5):

Just for illustration and learning reasons, three examples with `Fold`, `Do` and `Table`. Define

```
matrix1 := {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}
```

Then

```
Table[matrix1 = 2*matrix1 + 4, {100}]
```

prints all intermediate matrices

```
Do[matrix1 = 2*matrix1 + 4, {100}]
matrix1
```

and

```
f[x_] := 2 x + 4
Fold[f[#1] &, matrix1, Range[100]]
```

print the last result.